# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "firebase/app". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I've followed a YouTube tutorial on WebRTC video chat, so I've tried to write it. In localhost it worked, but as soon as I've uploaded it to firebase hosting it gives this error.
what can I do? I'm new in web developing so please be patient

main.hmtl

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>WebRtc Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <h2>Start Cam</h2>
  <div class ="videos">
    <span>
      <h3>Local</h3>
      <video id="webcamVideo" autoplay playsinline></video>
    </span>

    <span>
      <h3>Remote</h3>
      <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay playsinline></video>
    </span>
  </div>

  <button id="webcamButton">Start cam</button>

  <h2>New Call</h2>
  <button id="callButton">call</button>

  <input id="callInput"/>

  <button id="answerButton">Rispondi</button>
  <button id="hangupButton">Hangup</button>

  <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>


</body> 
</html>
```

Firebase.json

```
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "/",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

main.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};
```

Comment: Do you mind confirming that firebase is properly installed as a dependency in package.json? If not, that might be the problem.

Comment: It is installed correctly because in package.json : ``` "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^8.3.0"
  } ```

Comment: And you see the firebase module within the node_modules folder?

Comment: Yes, It is there

Comment: same issue here.  any hope with resolving this?

Comment: Having the same issue

Comment: I have the same issue, @Frank van Puffelen can you please help.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. I will tell you how I resolved it :

First try to import firebase modules from google server using CDN. see down here :

```
     import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-app.js";
  import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc, getDocs, collection } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-firestore.js";
```

this works very well. but for efficiency, I guess you want to load firebase modules on your computer using npm.
in that case you absolutely need module Bundlers like Webpack, Rollup, Parcel, Snowpack,... I used **Webpack**, they are alot of tutorials about it.

In case you are using a module bundler, it will compile your main.js file into another file, let's call it bundle.js.

then fix this:

```
<script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
```

to :

```
<script type="module" src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

or (depending on how you sets your paths)

```
<script type="module" src="bundle.js"></script>
```

so your are getting that error because your main.js is not compiled.

I hope that helps you. peace

Answer (score 0):

You can use CDN

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-app.js";
import {
  getAuth,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.0/firebase-auth.js";
```

⚠️ NOTE⚠️
When ever you need a service just change file name that the end of the link

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you built your application before deploying it?

I had to run `npm run build` then update `firebase.json` and `deploy` again to get rid of that error.

```json
// Firebase.json
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "dist", // where the bundled code has generated 
         .....
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

They follow the webpack approach, for this they must have node js installed.
https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/

Comment: Link only answer is useless. Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).